# Android - Add lines on TableLayout with TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, view, android-tablelayout

[image]

Hi! This is my TableLayout with TableRow and Button for each cell. I want a vertical and horizontal line for separate the cells, with the XML attributes.

```
      <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/table0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/x"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/LUN"
                    android:text="LUN"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                   .....

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/VEN"
                    android:text="VEN"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/SAB"
                    android:text="SAB"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/table1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/o1"
                    android:text="1°" >
                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bLUN1"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bMAR1"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp" />

                .....

                 ....
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/table2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/o2"
                    android:text="2°" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bLUN2"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp" />

               ....
```

So, i'd like to use lines like a simple View but i dont know how, sorry for the bad english!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shape xml like this and save it in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke android:width="2px" 
    color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

set this as background for each cell.

Comment: Will this solution maintain the border for each cell if the device orientation changes? I like it because it's so simple.

Comment: Yes it will maintain the border, but run it and check it out as border might be thin on the edges and thick in between. To solve this you will need to set border layout of the same width to entire table.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> TableLayout containers do not display border lines for their rows,
>   columns, or cells.

Since it is a subclass of View, in the onDraw() method for the TableLayout you can draw border lines like this:

```
myPaint.setColor(0xff000000);
//horizontal lines
for(int i = 2; i < heightfactor + 1; i++)
    c.drawLine(0, horz_spacing_factor * i,  cwidth,  horz_spacing_factor * i,  myPaint);
//vertical lines
for(int i = 2; i < widthfactor + 1; i++)
    c.drawLine(vert_spacing_factor * i, 0,  vert_spacing_factor * i, cwidth,  myPaint);
```